# Use dictwriter to write limited # of columns to CSV and also create computed column like in Excel

Tags: python, api, csv

Building off my former post here: [How to print data from API call into a CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62397498/how-to-print-data-from-api-call-into-a-csv-file/62397997#62397997)

The API call returns this

```
[Order({   'asset_class': 'us_equity',
'asset_id': '8a9-43b6-9b36-662f01e8fadd',
'canceled_at': None,
'client_order_id': 'e38a-b51c-349314bc6e9e',
'created_at': '2020-06-05T16:16:53.307491Z',
'expired_at': None,
'extended_hours': False,
'failed_at': None,
'filled_at': '2020-06-05T16:16:53.329Z',
'filled_avg_price': '7.8701',
'filled_qty': '45',
'id': '8-4888-9c7c-97bf8c2a3a16',
'legs': None,
'limit_price': '7.87',
'order_class': '',
'order_type': 'limit',
'qty': '45',
'replaced_at': None,
'replaced_by': None,
'replaces': None,
'side': 'sell',
'status': 'filled',
'stop_price': None,
'submitted_at': '2020-06-05T16:16:53.293859Z',
'symbol': 'CARS',
'time_in_force': 'day',
'type': 'limit',
'updated_at': '2020-06-08T11:21:51.411547Z'}), Order({   'asset_class': 'us_equity',
'asset_id': '1aef-42f4-9975-750dbcb3e67d',
'canceled_at': None,
'client_order_id': '2bde-4572-a5d0-bfc32c2bf31a',
'created_at': '2020-06-05T16:16:37.508176Z',
'expired_at': None,
'extended_hours': False,
'failed_at': None,
'filled_at': '2020-06-05T16:16:37.531Z',
'filled_avg_price': '10.8501',
'filled_qty': '26',
'id': '4256-472c-a5de-6ca9d6a21422',
'legs': None,
'limit_price': '10.85',
'order_class': '',
'order_type': 'limit',
'qty': '26',
'replaced_at': None,
'replaced_by': None,
'replaces': None,
'side': 'sell',
'status': 'filled',
'stop_price': None,
'submitted_at': '2020-06-05T16:16:37.494389Z',
'symbol': 'IGT',
'time_in_force': 'day',
'type': 'limit',
'updated_at': '2020-06-08T11:21:51.424963Z'})]
```

I'd like to repeat the exercise of writing to a CSV as linked in my other post but this time only write a subset of the columns from the API into a CSV. My first attempt here was instead of using the keys from the raw dictionary I would specify the fieldnames as a list, but then I'm having trouble accessing only the keys in the dict entry based on the list of filenames that I'm passing in.

```
with open('historical_orders.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['id', 'created_at', 'filled_at', 'canceled_at', 'replaced_at', 'symbol', 'asset_class', 'qty',
                  'filled_qty', 'filled_avg_price', 'order_class', 'order_type', 'type',
                  'side', 'time_in_force', 'limit_price',
                  'stop_price', 'status', 'extended_hours', 'legs']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    for order in closed_orders:
        writer.writerow(order.__dict__['_raw'].fieldnames)
```

I get AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'fieldnames'.

Additionally I'd like to add 1 more column that strips out the funky "created_at" value to a date and time. So instead of "created_at" = "'2020-06-05T16:16:53.307491Z'", I'd like to create a column date "'2020-06-05" and time "'16:16:53". I was thinking I could do this by adding a loop in each write row to write one field a time, but wasn't sure if there was a better way.

Can someone help me with these 2 issues?

Comment: what is this? `order.__dict__['_raw']` seems very suspect. Why do things that way? what is `order`? Please provide a [mcve]. Why not `order._raw`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga those details were in the linked post but I re-pasted above for reference. I assumed that the __dict__['_raw'] was grabbing the dictionary of the raw data. What exactly does the raw do? I looked online but could not find any definitions for it